# Passphrase Certificate Key on Apache reboot options

Tags: apache, security, ssl, automation, ssl-certificate

Currently there is this web in an apache server with SSL key with passphrase, so when the server restart you must manually unlock the key by entering the passphrase.

I know I could recreate the key without passphrase.

I also know I could use SSLPassPhraseDialog and auto-unlock the key with a script.

But doesn't seems right to me to protect the key with a passphrase, if this is going to be written down in a clear text file. Event though this file is root 000 file permissions.

What I'm I missing? Should I just remove the passphrase and focus on perimetral defense and other security methods?

I feel must be a third choice, the good one, that I'm not aware of.

What are the best choice to protect a certificate key on the apache server?

Thank you

Comment: I have seen both used (no passpharse, or store the passphrase in a user protected file).  I have never seen a third option...  And make sure these files are not accessible to Apache as content files ;0

Comment: Thank you Nic. 
Yeah, files are not accesible as content to apache, you mean are not under the www directory right?

Comment: Indeed.  It must be impossible to download these files as a web site user.